# XNA Processing, Windows Service, Handle, GraphicsDevice

Tags: c#, graphics, service, xna, device

I'm using the XNA library for image processing in GPU. All this must be done as a Windows Service (not forms).

When I create a GraphicsDevice, it requires a WindowsHandle. But the WindowService doesn't have a WindowsHandle. Even when the "window form" is created from the service, GraphicsDevice isn't created.

How to set the WindowsHandle for GraphicsDevice in WindowService?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you aren't constructing your GraphicsDevice using the GraphicsDeviceManager there is quite a bit of extra work you will have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to (can't?) create forms from a service. You certianly cannot access the GPU, [due to Session 0 Isolation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/58343489/Windows-Session-0-Isolation-Impact-on-GPU-as-Service).

Consider using auto-login and a standard desktop app. You can create an invisible form and bind the graphics device to that.